# How to convert month name to month number in a timeseries in DataFrame?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time-series

I have a column in my DataFrame with timeseries data as '01-Jun-2018'.
I need to convert the date to format '01-06-2018' for all the other months as well.
What should I do for this using pandas or even without pandas?

Comment: check `pd.to_datetime()`

Comment: `pd.to_datetime( '01-Jun-2018').strftime('%d-%m-%Y')`?

Answer (score 2):

First convert column to datetimes and then add [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) for strings in custom format - `DD-MM-YYYY`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

Or:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d-%b-%Y').dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

If need datetimes only omit `.dt.strftime`, but default format is `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: @Efran - Thank you, typo.